# Component in proteus

Tags: simulation, proteus, rotary

I want to make a rotary encoder in proteus since I don't have it in my proteus library but I can't find the schematic for it i dont know the components and layout needed to make it
https://uk.farnell.com/bourns/pec11r-4220f-s0012/incremental-encoder-12mm-60rpm/dp/2663526 the data sheet should be here

I saw this filter circuit in the data sheet I'm guessing it's that then what are the shaded lines under terminal c and a and b do they mean ground also the 5v at the top does that just mean I need to supply 5v to it when I use it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you link to the datasheet? you seem to have only included a screenshot, and that helps nobody…

Answer (score 0):

The symbol with shading is just ground.

The encoder is nothing more electrically than two pushbuttons operating with phase shift when you rotate the shaft.

The external components are just pull-ups to supply voltage and RC debounce filters before connecting these wires somewhere, like a schmitt trigger or MCU input pins.

Depening on your MCU, the supplied voltage needs to match what the MCU supports on IO pins.

Comment: It also has a momentary push button option how do I add that to the design?

Comment: @zug A push button is just a push button. I do not know how you would add a push button to a Proteus design, I have never used it. But that was not in your original question which is now answered. If you have new questions, then ask a new question.